# using window["webpackJsonp"] in background script in chrome extension to resolves to all installed modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

Want to resolves to all installed modules in chrome extension background script

```
                function getAllModules() {
                if (typeof _ !== 'undefined') {

                        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                            const id = _.uniqueId("fakeModule_");
                            window["webpackJsonp"](
                                [],
                                {
                                    [id]: function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
                                        resolve(__webpack_require__.c);
                                    }
                                },
                                [id]
                            );
                        });
                    }
                }
```

but `window["webpackJsonp"]` is not accisible in background script.

Comment: Extensions consist of many moving parts. Show us how and where exactly you're accessing it.

Comment: I am using this script but in background not in content 
https://gist.github.com/phpRajat/84c0f16f9d13f362bbd73328f5a29f84

Comment: It probably means you didn't use webpack or something overwrites it. Anyway, why do you need this low-level hack?

Comment: just experimenting with extensions, now I stuck  tried every thing

Comment: Well, this problem is not specific to extensions.